# why is .setColor(,,,) saying unable to find symbol in this program?

Tags: java, methods, constructor, awt, paint

When I run this program the code g2.setColor(fillColor) has a cannot find symbol error. is this a legacy issue? improper code?

> > > I typed this code in verbatim from page165 of the book "Big Java" by Cay Horstmann

```
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

/**
 * An applet that lets a user choose a color by specifying the fractions of 
 * red, green, and blue.
 */
    public class ColorApplet extends Applet
    {
        public ColorApplet()
        {
            String input;

            //Ask user for red, green, blue values
            input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("red: ");
            float red = Float.parseFloat(input);

            input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("green: ");
            float green = Float.parseFloat(input);

            input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("blue :");
            float blue = Float.parseFloat(input);

            //creates the color based on the RGB inputted values
            Color fillColor= new Color(red, green, blue);
        }

        public void paint(Graphics g)
        {
            Graphics2D g2= (Graphics2D)g;

            g2.setColor(fillColor);

            Rectangle square = new Rectangle((getWidth() - SQUARE_LENGTH)/2, 
            (getHeight() - SQUARE_LENGTH)/2, SQUARE_LENGTH, SQUARE_LENGTH);

            g2.fill(square);
        }

        private static final int SQUARE_LENGTH = 100;
    }
```

Comment: Graphics2D doesn't have a setColor method...

Comment: http://edelstein.pebbles.cs.cmu.edu/jadeite/main.php?api=java6&state=class&package=java.awt&class=Graphics#1095 @Solace but Graphics has, which is the super class

Answer (score 2):

`fillColor` is not declared in `paint` method. In your program `fillColor` has its scope in constructor only `Color fillColor= new Color(red, green, blue);` 
 You can make it instance variable to make it accessible like:

```
public class ColorApplet extends Applet
{
   Color fillColor;

// now in constructor
public ColorApplet()
{
...
...
 fillColor= new Color(red, green, blue);
}
```

Now you can use `fillColor` in `paint` method